# How to write a regular expression to match '012356789' (no 4)

Tags: regex

For now, I'm using `[012356789]`, but is there other way to implement "all numbers without 4" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
[0-35-9]
```

Comment: This regex should also match `aaa0aaa`.

Comment: @npinti: Depends on how you use it.

Answer (score 4):

To make sure that the string contains only numbers excluding the number `4`, you could use this: `^[0-35-9]+$`. The `^` denotes the start of the string, `[0-35-9]` denotes any number excluding the number `4`, the `+` denotes one or more and the `$` the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

For this simple situation what the other suggested is more than enough. For more complex situations you could use something like:

```
(?!4)[0-9]
```

This would be good when you are using character classes and you want to exclude a single letter. (any letter but `x` for example). It means: `not followed by 4, any digit 0-9`

As noted by @stema, this will make the regular expression more "complex" in the long run. If you want to add a quantifier you have two "regex elements" instead of one, so you need to:

```
(?:(?!4)[0-9])
```

(the `?:` means that the group isn't a capturing group)

Comment: OK, but if you want to use it together with a quantifier you need to group it first like this `(?:(?!4)[0-9])+`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be

```
[^\D4]
```

`\D` is not a digit, so within a negated character class it would match a digit, and then you can add the "4" to the negated class to exclude it from the allowed characters.

See it [here on regexr](http://regexr.com?31ihr)

Comment: Depending on the regex dialect, `\d` could be non-european digits, so be aware :-)